# SDL_RenderDrawPoint not working

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

If i use this code:

```
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer.get(), 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF );       
                SDL_RenderDrawLine( renderer.get(), 0, 480 / 2, 640, 480 / 2 );

                //Draw vertical line of yellow dots
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer.get(), 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF );
                for( int i = 0; i < 480; i += 4 )
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint( renderer.get(), 640 / 2, i );
                }
```

It will draw yellow points and blue line, but if i comment SDL_RenderDrawLine, it will draw nothing. What is wrong?

This will happen too, if i use this code and somewhere in code (after a while) i want to use SDL_RenderDrawPoint or SDL_RenderDrawPoints.

I am using lastest SDL library and Linux Mint.

Comment: Check the return value of the function calls and in case of error use `SDL_GetError()` to print an error message. Example: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError

Comment: It returns code 0, success. So, i dont know.

Comment: Sorry, in SDL_GetError() is invalid renderer. But why it returns 0?

Comment: Are you checking all of your function calls? Which is the first one to return 0 with invalid renderer and is that with or without `SDL_RenderDrawLine` commented out?

Comment: I am checking every SDL function call (in app) and every returns 0, but in error is invalid renderer.